# How to correctly post JSON to a many to one relationship

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two models, movie and review, and they have a one to many relationship. You can see I've included an ICollection of reviews in Movie and in Review I've added a foreign key and navigational property.

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string imdbId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    //Navigational Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
public class Review
{
    public int ReviewID { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public int goreRating { get; set; }
    public int shockRating { get; set; }
    public int jumpRating { get; set; }
    public int plotRating { get; set; }
    public int supernaturalRating { get; set; }
    public int starRating { get; set; }

}
```

I am trying to post reviews to my controller, but looking at the JSON format expected in Swagger, my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "reviewID": 0,
  "movie": {
    "movieId": 0,
    "imdbId": "string",
    "title": "string",
    "genres": [
      {
        "genreId": 0,
        "movies": [
          null
        ]
      }
    ],
    "reviews": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "goreRating": 0,
  "shockRating": 0,
  "jumpRating": 0,
  "plotRating": 0,
  "supernaturalRating": 0,
  "starRating": 0
}
```

**I'd like to be able to send just the review data and the movie id.** If I try to send this whole JSON blob I get an error like *"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"*. But from the format of the JSON object and the additional reviews array inside the JSON, I know I'm off the mark.

I would like to know how this JSON can be sent to create a valid entry for review, linked to a movieId, or if (and how) my models should modified to achieve the desired result if they are incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I think it would be a better idea to write a dto like "CreateReview". This class has only the properties that you want the user to be able to post to the api when creating a new review.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a ViewModel (named ReviewViewModel), and use it to pass data from view to controller. Then, in the controller, create a Review Model instance and find the Movie based on the MoviedId, then, set the Reivew Model value based on the ReviewViewModel and the Movie. Code as below:

```
public class ReviewViewModel
{
    public int ReviewID { get; set; } 
    public int MovieId{ get; set; }    // Movie Id, 
    public int goreRating { get; set; }
    public int shockRating { get; set; }
    public int jumpRating { get; set; }
    public int plotRating { get; set; }
    public int supernaturalRating { get; set; }
    public int starRating { get; set; }

}
```

View page: When click the Create button, use JQuery Ajax to send ReviewViewModel to the controller:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnCreate").click(function () { 
                var review = {};
                review.ReviewID = $("#ReviewID").val();
                review.MovieID = $("#MovieID").val();
                review.goreRating = $("#goreRating").val();
                review.shockRating = $("#shockRating").val();
                review.jumpRating = $("#jumpRating").val();
                review.plotRating = $("#plotRating").val();
                review.supernaturalRating = $("#supernaturalRating").val();
                review.starRating = $("#starRating").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AddReview",
                    method: "Post",
                    data: review,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                })

            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult AddReview()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddReview(ReviewViewModel reviewViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //find the movie based on the reviewViewModel.MovieID
        // var movie = //_dbcontext.Movies.Where(c=>c.MovieID == reviewViewModel.MovieID).FirstOrDefault();

        var review = new Review();
        review.starRating = reviewViewModel.starRating;
        //review.Movie == movie //set the existing movie or create a new movie instance.

        //add review to database via dbcontext.
        //save changes.
    }
    return View();
}
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]